# About us page with facebook,google plus icons

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

In the app that i am developing there is 4 icons of social networking app buttons like Facebook, Twitter, linkedIn and Google+ in about us page. now onclick of those buttons i need to post url and text in the corresponding social networking app.

ie: when i click on facebook button  URL and text(our aim is to.....) must be posted in facebook.

in order to do this i do know that there is Intent action send code:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setType("text/plain");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Sharing URL");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "http://www.url.com");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Share URL"));
```

by using the above code all the other social apps will be shown in list but is there a way in the above code to open only respective social app say for eg: call only facebook.

```
or in order to perform share as i want must include facebook SDK to my app?
```

Like:

[image: about_us]

Comment: have a look to this one http://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/social/implementFacebook/#socialplugin

Comment: i guess it supports only facebook and twitter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, Its not necessary to integrate every social media sdk just to share link and text from android app. Can share link and text with the help of `Intent.ACTION_SEND` this link<`http://kalisandroid.blogspot.in/2014/06/introduction-will-help-to-share-your.html`> helped me for Facebook, LinkedIn, Twitter and for Google plus below is the code.

Google plus code:

```
googlePlus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // share_image_text_GPLUS();

                Intent shareIntent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder
                        .from(getActivity())
                        .setText("http://link-you-wish-to-share-in-googleplus/")
                        .setType("text/plain").getIntent()
                        .setPackage("com.google.android.apps.plus");
                startActivity(shareIntent);
            }
        });
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with the help of Facebook-Sdk , Just google tutorials for it and you will get or otherwise go to  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share

This might help you what you are trying to implement!

Comment: then for google+ , twitter and linkedIn i must use respective sdk?

Comment: You can share via intent if you target all these social media.. otherwise get the available sdks Edit: But by including those sdks will make your app more flexible for sharing on fb and twitter